# need russian keyboard option I DO NOT have a GNOME desktop have ubuntu

Tags: keyboard-layout

I upgraded to 13.10, and need to use my Russian keyboard option I had in 12.10
I DO NOT have a GNOME desktop - says ubuntu desktop

Comment: Have you tried the system settings?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu desktop has mostly the same settings for Gnome Desktop - search for 'keyboard' settings and open them
[image]

Click 'Layout Settings'
[image]

Then click the `+`, add the Russian layout and move it to the top of the list

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Glad it worked :-) - mark at as answered if you think it is.